# ssh: (Locked out) Google 2 factor Authentication asking password again and again

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, password, vnc

I enabled google 2 factor authentication for my server, but it started acting weirdly and I am locked out. I have access to VNC, but my password has a special symbol `@` and I am unable to input that via VNC. I am locked out.
[image]

Comment: Reboot the server single-user and brute-force the password?

Comment: That is the problem. If I reboot, the VNC wakes up only at login screen!! I am unable to access the GRUB now.. :(

Comment: Is this a virtual or a physical server?

Comment: @MadHatter Virtual

Comment: You don't say what virtualisation technology it is.  Are you sure it's a proper virtual server, or is it just a container?  If it is a real VPS, you need to work with the vritualisation provider to find out why you can't get "remote console" access at the GRUB phase.

Comment: I am getting the VNC login screen.. But the issue is my password has @ in it which I am unable to input via VNC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45187/discussion-between-madhatter-and-sibidharan).

Comment: @MadHatter It is a VPS. Virtual Private Server

Comment: Glad we could fix it, Sibidharan.  By the way, did you zero out root's password, or replace it with a known hash?  (Just so I can get the answer precise.)

Comment: @MadHatter I zeroed it out and set a new password using `passwd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the chat log may or may not still show, the underlying problem was that non-alphanumeric characters weren't being correctly transmitted by the VNC-based virtual console, so there was no way to type an `@` character.  The solution was booting the VPS off rescue media, using UpCloud's interface for booting from virtual media, and zeroing out the root password from the `/etc/shadow` file.